# How to import Zipped file into Postgres Table

Tags: postgresql, zip

I would like to important a file into my Postgresql system(specificly RedShift). I have found a arguement for copy that allows importing a gzip file. But the provider for the data I am trying to include in my system only produces the data in a .zip. Any built in postgres commands for opening a .zip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within Postgres:

```
COPY table_name FROM PROGRAM 'unzip -p input.csv.zip' DELIMITER ',';
```

From the man page for `unzip -p`:

```
-p     extract files to pipe (stdout).  Nothing but the file data is sent to stdout, and the files are always extracted  in  binary
       format, just as they are stored (no conversions).
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do something like

```
unzip -c myfile.zip | gzip myfile.gz
```

Easy enough to automate if you have enough files.

Comment: File is not being stored locally and database is not local.

Comment: Ug. Well that makes it tough because I don't think amzn has any option for that.  Can you get access to exec psql on the server where file is stored and connect that way?  Otherwise might have to send the file through a middle-man server where you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
unzip -c /path/to/.zip | psql -U user
```

The 'user' must be have super user right else you will get a

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
```

To learn more about this [see here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/backup.html).

Basically this command is used in handling large databases

Comment: Alternatively, you can also pipe into `unzip` (or `gunzip` in my case). Consider `cat /path/to/.zip | unzip -c | psql -U user` (simplified for your case)

Answer (score 1):

This might only work when loading redshift from S3, but you can actually just include a "gzip" flag when copying data to redshift tables, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-gzip-compressed-data-files-from-S3.html):

This is the format that works for me if my s3 bucket contains a gzipped .csv.

```
copy <table> from 's3://mybucket/<foldername> '<aws-auth-args>' delimiter ',' gzip;
```